# How do I check for valid IDs for a PHP model?

Tags: php, database-design, model

I have database tables in MySQL that have a primary keys defined as follows:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I have already created models for the tables. I'm using Zend Framework v1, without an ORM, but this question should apply for all model implementations.

Now I want to create a function that allows me to grab by `id`:

```
public static function getById ($id) {

    $id = intval($id);

    if ($id < 1) {
        throw new Exception('bad id');
    }

    // business logic and stuff

    return $stuff;
}
```

The reason for this approach was twofold. Firstly, form input, including numbers, is often read from the view as a string. Secondly, invalid strings (such as `'asdf'`) would become zero after casting, thereby causing the exception to fire. However, there are many invalid strings that may still bypass the check:

```
echo intval('1asdf');
```

Output:

```
1
```

Other approaches I have tried include:

```
if (intval($id) === 0)

if ($id == intval($id))
```

What is the best way to validate the id in the model? I want it to accept integers greater than 0, and strings that are valid positive integers.

I would prefer something with a very low time cost. This is the reason I am not using regex to validate. These calls will be used everywhere in the application, and I cannot afford the overhead.

Comment: you can try `Zend_Validate_Digit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand why you are going through so much trouble just to validate your input. Simply use the php functions **is_numeric()** and **htmlentities()** to check your input before passing it to your SQL logic. Moreover an Invalid Numeric ID (which isnt present in your database) will return *null* output when SQL against it is executed and that should'nt be an issue.

References:

[is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

[htmlentites()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: `is_numeric` is the way to go here. OP is attacking this problem wrong